# API authentication in R - unable to pass auth token as header

Tags: r, api, httr

I am looking to do a simple GET request (from the Aplos API) in R using the httr package. I'm able to obtain a temporary token by authenticating with an API key, but then I get a 401 "Token could not be located" once trying to use the token to make an actual GET request. Would appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

```
AplosURL <- "https://www.aplos.com/hermes/api/v1/auth/"
AplosAPIkey <- "XYZ"
AplosAuth <- GET(paste0(AplosURL,AplosAPIkey))
AplosAuthContent <- content(AplosAuth, "parsed")
AplosAuthToken <- AplosAuthContent$data$token
#This is where the error occurs
GET("https://www.aplos.com/hermes/api/v1/accounts",  
    add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer:", AplosAuthToken)))
```

This is a Python snippet provided by the API documentation:

```
def api_accounts_get(api_base_url, api_id, api_access_token):
    # This should print a contact from Aplos.
    # Lets show what we're doing.
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer: {}'.format(api_access_token)}
    print 'geting URL: {}accounts'.format(api_base_url)
    print 'With headers: {}'.format(headers)

    # Actual request goes here.
    r = requests.get('{}accounts'.format(api_base_url), headers=headers)
    api_error_handling(r.status_code)
    response = r.json()
    print 'JSON response: {}'.format(response)
    return (response)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the python example, the return of the auth code block is the api_bearer_token which is base64 decoded and rsa decrypted (using your key) before it can be used.

```
...
api_token_encrypted = data['data']['token']
api_bearer_token = rsa.decrypt(base64.decodestring(api_token_encrypted), api_user_key)

return(api_bearer_token)
```

That decoded token is then used in the api call to get the accounts.

The second issue I see is that your Authorization header does not match the example's header. Specifically, you are missing the space after "Bearer:"

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer: {}'.format(api_access_token)}
```

vs

```
add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer:", AplosAuthToken)))
```

Likely after addressing both of these you should be able to proceed.

Comment: `paste("Bearer:", AplosAuthToken)` should in fact put a space between "Bearer:" and the token, because by default `paste` separates strings with a space